# Hazelcast Rolling Upgrade between non-subsequent minor versions

Tags: upgrade, hazelcast, rolling-computation

Starting with Hazelcast Enterprise 3.8, each next minor version released will be compatible with the ***previous*** one. For example, it will be possible to perform a rolling upgrade on a cluster running Hazelcast Enterprise 3.8 to Hazelcast Enterprise 3.9 whenever that is released.

Is there any plan to support rolling upgrades between non-subsequent minor versions in future?

For e.g. from 3.8  to 3.11 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Rolling Upgrades can and will only be used with subsequent versions.